# why float right is not working also used important?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I have three image buttons in my header which is in right side as show in image ,I am trying to add three buttons on header .But it is not taking **float:right** and **margin-right** .I need to make like this please check image ![enter image description here][1]

I have  **"+"** and search and funnel image on right side .so to make this button on right side ?
here is my plunker

```
<ion-header-bar align-title="" class="bar-balanced">
  <a class="button button-clear  icon-right ion-chevron-right ">
  </a>

  <h1 class="title">Title!</h1>
  <div style="float:right!important;border:1px solid red ;margin-right:10px">
  <a class="button button-icon icon ion-plus"></a>
  <a class="button button-icon icon ion-search"></a>
  <a class="button button-icon icon ion-funnel"></a>
  </div>

</ion-header-bar>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `float:right` with `position: absolute;`
`right: 10px;`

http://plnkr.co/edit/u89uQlz7VOGiznLmAoDj?p=preview

Comment: please give plunker ..for check

Comment: @Shruti why don't u just try it?